# Add delay to gtest Test Case

Tags: c++, sleep, googletest

I'm using google test framework for testing hardware Ethernet switch. Some operations (e.x. enabling RSTP) take time to proceed. So I need to implement some sort of a `Sleep()` function inside the test case:

```
TEST_F(RSTP, enableRSTP) {
    snmp.set(OID, Integer32(3));
    // after changing value switch is unavailable
    // so I need to wait before request
    auto result = snmp.get(OID);
    auto res = std::get<Integer32>(result);
    ASSERT_EQ(res, Integer32(3));
}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is okay but you can use something as simple as
`std::this_thread::sleep_for`

Comment: are you using c++11?

Comment: If not, what OS do you use?

Comment: @WernerErasmus I'm on VS2017 with  /std:c++latest option

Comment: @Alexandr, in that case, see my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments, you could just use (c++14):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
TEST_F(RSTP, enableRSTP) {
  ...
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
  ...
}
```

... or for c++11, replace `2s` with:

```
std::chrono::seconds(2)
```

If you don't use >= c++11, then this becomes an OS specific question (not standard c++)

Comment: Thank you! Works just like I need it