# this_thread::sleep_for is not working in google test in WSL

Tags: c++, googletest, windows-subsystem-for-linux, c++-chrono

I am trying to sleep in Google test. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467980/add-delay-to-gtest-test-case), I can use the following:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
TEST_F(TestSuite, TestOne) {
    // f1();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    // f2();
}
```

I put this command in the Test, but it does not change anything. Code executes quickly as it omitted the sleep. I am using g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0.
What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Is your code/test really executed? Try add some log, breakpoint or failing test code and see is it working. Or maybe your test exits before `sleep_for` (at `f1` for example)

Comment: In code, I put sleep_for inside for loop which couts array, but it is printed immediately.

Comment: Sorry for stupid assumption, but... have your code rebuilt? Did you also try change something else except sleep_for? Maybe change some text message and see did it really changed in output?

Comment: Your example (although not complete) works correctly. You have the problem somewhere else. Show: Fixture definition, f1, f2 definitions, command used to run the tests, console output.

Comment: I removed everything from test leaving it like this:cout; sleep; cout;  
It executed immediately. I am running it in WSL, maybe that's the issue, I will check it

Comment: I tested exactly the same code on Linux and it works properly.
The above code does not sleep in the Windows Subsystem for Linux.
I don't know what causes this error, maybe something related to thread library.

Comment: Does mostly empty program in "Windows Subsystem for Linux" sleep if it call just from `main`? (Not test, just new app) Maybe problem in running programs under this subsystem

Comment: No. Program like this  
std::cout << "Hello " << std::flush;  
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));  
std::cout << "World\n";  
Prints Hello World immediately.

Comment: This seems to be a WSL bug. Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230252/sleep-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-20-04-wsl) and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4898).

Answer (score 0):

Does your test really execute? I'd recommend to put temporary `std::cout << "STARTING TEST" << std::endl;` in the beginning of the test and check if you can see those words on the output.

Answer (score 0):

Well... As I understand, the problem is in WSL, see this link: [Unpredictable behaviour of std::sleep_for on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493041/unpredictable-behaviour-of-stdsleep-for-on-windows-10).

Try to build your sources with native compilers for Windows: MSVC, MinGW or Cygwin. If your code uses Linux-specific things, probably Cygwin will be better (easier to build code or easier to port it). Or you can try using some Linux system natively. Sorry, I don't know what to advice else...